# How do I start Kestrel in a .NetCore project in Docker image

Tags: docker, ssl, .net-core

I have created a web app in .NET core 2.1 with SSL certificates. It is running fine  when deploying to our test server. Now I am trying to create a Docker image with SSL certificates.

This is how I create the image:

[Windows cmd commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPs6Y.png)

This is how I set up yml

[docker-compose.override.prod.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLLDT.png)

I can create the docker image and get OK to that but I get the following error: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] unable to start Kestrel

I have verified that the SSL certificate is created and that the project has a link to the certificate.

[Link to certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOadc.png)

Comment: Posting code text instead of images would make it much easier for us to give a potential answer.  Are you using a linux docker image or windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start up Krestel with SSL support

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);  // http:localhost:5000
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);         // http:*:80
    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 443, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password");
    });
})
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

Where the PFX file will have to be copied into the docker image by the appropriate command in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think actually the solution you gave is for .NET core 2.0. I found this article and followed the instructions to get it running: http://parsstudent.com/asp-net-core-2-1-application-in-docker-with-https-enabled/